# Sorting a generic list on arbitrary property alphanumerically in c#

Tags: c#, .net, list, sorting, alphanumeric

Is it possible to sort a generic list on arbitrary property alphanumerically in c#? Let me know if the question is not clear and I will come up with an example.

Thanks in advance

Note: I have found this link that does it but not alphanumerically. Can anyone help me out?
http://blog.codewrench.net/2009/04/14/sorting-a-generic-list-on-arbitrary-property/

Comment: can you please explain it with example

Comment: What do you mean "alphanumerically"? You really need to give an example of what you're trying to do.

Comment: Let's say I have the following string:
 string[] highways = new string[]
 {
     "100F",
     "50F",
     "SR100",
     "SR9"
 };
I want the output to be:

50F
100F
SR9
SR100

Comment: And right now I have that name as a property in a class. There is also a list that contains the objects created from that class. Now I need to sort the objects of this list based on the Name property.

Comment: list<myClass> --> the list (Implements IList)
myClass has 2 properties --> Name and Code
I would like to sort the items in the list based on Names

Comment: @Sev: Please edit your post when adding new information to your question, don't just add comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a fast alphanumeric sort (can be used for other sorts with numerics too).

C# Alphanumeric Sorting http://www.dotnetperls.com/alphanumeric-sorting

```
public class AlphanumComparatorFast : IComparer
{
    public int Compare(object x, object y)
    {
    string s1 = x as string;
    if (s1 == null)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    string s2 = y as string;
    if (s2 == null)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    int len1 = s1.Length;
    int len2 = s2.Length;
    int marker1 = 0;
    int marker2 = 0;

    // Walk through two the strings with two markers.
    while (marker1 < len1 && marker2 < len2)
    {
        char ch1 = s1[marker1];
        char ch2 = s2[marker2];

        // Some buffers we can build up characters in for each chunk.
        char[] space1 = new char[len1];
        int loc1 = 0;
        char[] space2 = new char[len2];
        int loc2 = 0;

        // Walk through all following characters that are digits or
        // characters in BOTH strings starting at the appropriate marker.
        // Collect char arrays.
        do
        {
        space1[loc1++] = ch1;
        marker1++;

        if (marker1 < len1)
        {
            ch1 = s1[marker1];
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }
        } while (char.IsDigit(ch1) == char.IsDigit(space1[0]));

        do
        {
        space2[loc2++] = ch2;
        marker2++;

        if (marker2 < len2)
        {
            ch2 = s2[marker2];
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }
        } while (char.IsDigit(ch2) == char.IsDigit(space2[0]));

        // If we have collected numbers, compare them numerically.
        // Otherwise, if we have strings, compare them alphabetically.
        string str1 = new string(space1);
        string str2 = new string(space2);

        int result;

        if (char.IsDigit(space1[0]) && char.IsDigit(space2[0]))
        {
        int thisNumericChunk = int.Parse(str1);
        int thatNumericChunk = int.Parse(str2);
        result = thisNumericChunk.CompareTo(thatNumericChunk);
        }
        else
        {
        result = str1.CompareTo(str2);
        }

        if (result != 0)
        {
        return result;
        }
    }
    return len1 - len2;
    }
}
```

usage

```
var unordered = new[] { "100F", "50F", "SR100", "SR9" };
var ordered = unordered.OrderBy(s => s, new AlphanumComparatorFast());
```

and here is a nice article about the problem:

Sorting for Humans : Natural Sort Order http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/12/sorting-for-humans-natural-sort-order.html

Comment: If I had a list of type string this solution would work but I have objects of a class in my list. One of the properties is the Name property. I need to sort the objects using the name + alphanumerically

Comment: yourList.OrderBy(yourListItem => yourListItem.YourStringProperty, new AlphanumComparatorFast());

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that by "alphanumerically", you mean such a sorting:

```
01a
02a
02b
0a
1a
1b
a
b
c
...
```

You could use the [`OrderBY`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534966.aspx) method of LINQ:

```
IEnumerable<T> myObjects = myObjects.OrderBy(x => x.SomeProperty);
```

---

**EDIT based on PO inputs:**

Unfortunately, that won't work simply the way you want it (`100F 50F SR100 SR9` goes to `50F 100F SR9 SR100`). But you could use the overloaded [`OrderBy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549422.aspx) and implement your desired `IComparer`.